# How to make a bullet list align with text in css?

Tags: css, list

[image]

The image demonstrates the problem. I want the bullet list to be aligned with the text, not indented.

This must be modified in css i guess, because source is:

```
            <p>This is a test :)</p>

<ul>

<li>Test1</li>

<li>Test2</li>

<li>Test3</li>

<li>Test4</li>

</ul>

<p><strong>Bla bla</strong></p>

<p><strong>Dette er en test</strong></p>

<p><strong><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-weight: normal;"><strong>Dette er en test</strong></span></strong></p>

<p><strong>Dette er en test</strong></p>

<p><strong><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-weight: normal;"><strong>Dette er en test</strong></span></strong></p>
        </div>
```

So how can I remove the padding/margin from left in this bull list? I tried `margin: 0; padding: 0;` did not work out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I get the bullet points of a <ul> to center with the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977320/how-do-i-get-the-bullet-points-of-a-ul-to-center-with-the-text)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Apply `padding-left: 0` and change the list style position to inside:

```
ul  {
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
   list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Example link http://jsfiddle.net/vF5HF/

Comment: Keep in mind `list-style-position:inside` will make it so the bullet is basically in the text, so if your text wraps the bullet won't be separated the text. It looks pretty bad if you ask me.

Comment: He's asking for a non-idented, text-aligned list...it does look pretty bad, but that's what he's looking for ;)

Answer (score 24):

```
ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
li {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: This answer will usually be better as it keeps text in a list item that spans multiple lines aligned.

Comment: Also, the distance from the bullet to the item text can be increased by additionally using `padding-left` on the list item. Nice, simple, and above all flexible solution. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: This seems like the simplest answer, but couldn't it just be replaced with `ul { padding-left: 1em; }`?

Comment: With this solution, the alignment is not consistent between browser: on Safari macOS, the bullet appear to much on the left.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Bullet alignment</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-size: 14pt; margin: 100px; background-color: #f2f2f2; }
        ul { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 2em; list-style-type: none; }
        li:before {
            content: "\2713";
            text-align: left;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 0 0 -2em;
            width: 2em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Bullet alignment &#x1F608;</p>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
</ul>
<p>That’s all Folks</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the best answer here. The only change I would make is to use content: "\2022" with font-weight: bold since the OP requested bullets.

Comment: If your `li` contains `p` or `div` elements, this will cause alignment problems  that have to be patched with further CSS.

Answer (score 2):

As @NicolaPasqui mentioned, for your problem you should use:

```
ul {
  padding-left: 0
}

ul li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

When setting list-style-position to **inside**, the bullet will be **inside the list item**.

[image]

Unlike setting it to **outside**, where the bullet will be **outside the list item**.

[image]

There is a great article about **bullet style** I think you could benefit from [here](https://kolosek.com/css-bullet-style/).