# How can I center the bullet points in an HTML list?

Tags: html, list

I have the following HTML and CSS on a client's website:

```
<ul class="new">
<li>OWNER OCCUPIED LOAN PROPERTY</li>
<li>INVESTMENT LOAN</li>
<li>FIRST HOME BUYER</li>
<li>REFINANCING</li>
</ul>

ul.new {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I'd like to center the bullet points. Can you help me do that please? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I get the bullet points of a <ul> to center with the text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977320/how-do-i-get-the-bullet-points-of-a-ul-to-center-with-the-text)

Comment: Ever had a look in a HTML book or reference?

Answer (score 2):

If you add `list-style-position: inside;` into the `.new`, like this:

```
ul.new {
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: center;
}
```

It will center the list as well as the bullets. However, I don't know if this is how you would like them to be centered, or if you want the bullets to be aligned together. I'll leave an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/khkx04t4/) so you can see.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Apologies for the delay. Yes, I was after the bullets to be aligned in a vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

please add Below Css and Check your output.
i think you want that.

```
ul.new {
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```