# Center list elements

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm trying to center list items with the `text-align:center` property but it leaves the jot notes behind while the text is centered. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are jot notes? It might help to create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the issue.

Comment: The dots that come with uls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I get the bullet points of a <ul> to center with the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977320/how-do-i-get-the-bullet-points-of-a-ul-to-center-with-the-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of methods to center these elements

1- Using `<center>` element:

```
<div id="one">Number One</div>
<div id="two">Number Two</div>
<div id="three">Number Three</div>
```

2- Using CSS code like:

```
div {
position: absolute; // or position: fixed;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50% , 0%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50% , 0%);
}
```

or

```
.divscontainer {
text-align: center;
}

.perdiv {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Provide us an example of your written code to edit it (not to create a new code then give it to you !) ;)